# Creating a bevel car decal like effect?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create a 3D bevelled version of my own logo 
[image]

And make it look something like this:
[image]
or this 
[image]

Where it is beveled in the middle.
Currently I have tried taking in a svg file into blender, tried their curve bevel options. It just bevelled in depth not in width

I even tried to convert my curve into mesh and then extruded/scaled in the middle but due to the curve – mesh conversion the faces wouldn’t scale uniformly and it was all over the place. I was wondering if there was another way to create something like this?

Thanks 
Phoenix

Edit: 
This what happens when I use the curve bevel
[image]
And this is what happens when I have converted to mesh and tried to scale it in.
[image] 
Perhaps it is my design or the way the curve is converted but the points seem to go crazy.

Comment: Hi, please don't include just links for images: save the example picture on your computer, then upload it using the question editor tool, that will embed the image in your post and make easier for others to understand your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your curve to full, add some depth and leave the resolution at 0 it seems that it will just create the look you are going for. You need to set the shading to flat so you can see the sharp edge.

[image]

There is also a star curve that you can tweak with the curve settings to get the desired look of a Mercedes star. Not sure it will yield the perfect results for any shape, but you could try.

Settings for star:
[image]

Comment: I have tried many different variations of the curve settings. I think because my logo/shape isn’t uniformly even it doesn’t work as well as the Audi logo. 

I think due to my logos shape I might have to just hand model it from scratch. I was just seeing /hoping there was a trick I may have missed with the curve editor settings. Or a different way all together. 
I appreciate the fast response. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to design the logos from scratch in blender. Use the svg as a reference but model it from the ground up. Depending on the shape of your logo this can be quite fast.

E.g. Audi logo:

1. Spin a contour describing the profile of one ring to create a ring
2. Array modify one ring into four (Adjust distance to match original)
3. Boolean modify if needed to join the rings